# TeamCity deployer goes overtime while deploying code to a server

Tags: teamcity

I am using TeamCity Deployer for code deployment.

The issue I am facing has never happened before for me. The code I am trying to deploy is taking forever, from the build it looks like it is stuck at a sql script, but there since the process has not exited, I can't say for sure.

It does deploy to my DEV server, but not to another TEST server. Goes "overtime" on the TEST server.

**Could anyone tell what could be causing this issue ? and how to find it out?**

Comment: Please add more information (like logs). I tried to help you anyways...

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the logs is hard to say. Probably would be:

- **An environment problem**: Your TEST server is not configured as DEV server. Either SQL server is not correctly setup or credentials are not working, etc. You can open both servers and compare them.
- **A connectivity problem**: Your Build Agent have access to DEV but don't have access to TEST.

Apart of this, your deploy seems "**failing to fail**". I will address that too.

Also if I were you I would add a temporary **Build Failure Condition** to force the fail of the build and make the build red. You can add **"it runs longer than x minutes"** or **"Fail build on specific text in build log"**. This wouldn't fix your problem but you will have a red build that is much better than a stuck build...

Comment: Thanks ! Although, my issue is solved but I still don't know what caused it. I ran the SQL script in my TEST environment and it took a while to execute, probably updated some records. I ran the query again and it competed in a second may be didnt update any records, after which I pushed the code for deployment again and it build fine this time.